# How to make mysql query from subqueries combine the 2 results in to 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Questions:**

How to make this query results combine into 1 result?

```
    select *, count(winner) as count 
    from (select case radiant_win 
                when 1 then radiant_name 
                else dire_name 
            end as winner, 
            radiant_team_id, 
            dire_team_id,
            series_id,
            series_type
        from matches 
        where leagueid = 2096 and 
              start_time >= 1415938900 and 
             ((radiant_team_id= 1848158 and dire_team_id= 15) 
               or (radiant_team_id= 15 and dire_team_id= 1848158)) 
        ) as temp
    group by winner;
```

**Current Results**

*Below is the current query results*

[image: Results from the query]

**Desired Results**

*Below is my desired results*

[image: Desired results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to summarize all the matches between two teams and count how many times each of them was the winner, if so:

To simplify things, create a view:

```
create view v_matches as
select radiant_team_id as team1_id, radiant_win as team1_win, dire_team_id as team2_id, 1 - radiant_win as team2_win, leagueid, start_time, series_id, series_type
from matches
union 
select dire_team_id as team1_id, 1 - radiant_win as team1_win, radiant_team_id as team2_id, radiant_win as team2_win, leagueid, start_time, series_id, series_type
from matches
```

And then:

```
select team1_id, sum(team1_win) as team1_wins, team2_id, sum(team2_win) as team2_wins, series_id, series_type 
from v_matches
where leagueid = 2096 and start_time >= 1415938900 
  and team1_id = 1848158 and team2_id = 15
```

You can add team names to the view or join the second query with your `teams` table.